# Function returns undefined in Javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, xmlhttprequest

Can not figure it out how to return value (string) from this function:

```
function loadPage(url) {
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.open("GET", url, true);
    xhttp.send();

    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
            //var html = xhttp.responseText
            var html = document.documentElement.outerHTML;
            return html
        }
    }
}

console.log(loadPage("http://stops.lt/vilnius/#trol/2/a-b"))
```

When I use `console.log(html)` inside `xhttp.onreadystatechange` it prints correct results, but I don't understand how to return `loadPage(url)`. Tried both `return xhttp.onreadystatechange` and `return xhttp.onreadystatechange()` and none of these works.

Comment: async programming 101: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14220323/6567275 please read at least the ajax-part

Comment: Thanks for the link. I'm very new to Javascript. This is part of my first script ever written in js.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Fuction loadPage is async, you need to use callback function(or Promise):

```
function loadPage(url, cb) {
    var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhttp.open("GET", url, true);
    xhttp.send();

    xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (xhttp.readyState == 4 && xhttp.status == 200) {
            //var html = xhttp.responseText
            var html = document.documentElement.outerHTML;
            cb(html);
        }
    }
}
loadPage("http://stops.lt/vilnius/#trol/2/a-b", function(html){
    console.log(html);
});
```

Comment: Promises aren't supported very well (e.g. IE11), just use callbacks.